# no networks detected on HP EliteBook G2 745

Tags: network-manager, broadcom, hp

I'm having trouble getting the WiFi working (EliteBook g2 745 using broadcom bcm43228 WiFi card) on Ubuntu GNOME (shell version 3.18.5, kernel version 4.13.0). The bcmwl-kernel-source appears to be installed correctly, however when I click on *Select Network* in the top-right-corner menu the dialog box shows *No Networks*.

The WiFi card works fine with Windows (dual-boot setup) and is neither 
hard nor soft blocked. Secure boot is disabled in bios. The Kernel driver in use is *wl*. Tried installing *linux-headers-generic* and then reinstalling *bcmwl-kernel-source* but no luck. So far I've been using USB WiFi adaptor with no problem whatsoever. Here are the results of wireless-info diagnostic script:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fz65kNrnD4/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have crawled through numerous forums but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the issue wasn't within the drivers/kernel at all. I've read up on:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/broadcom-sta/+bug/1343151

and

https://community.hpe.com/t5/Networking/wifi-and-brightness-issues-with-EliteBook-755-on-Ubuntu-14-04/m-p/6568286/highlight/false#M9589

and, well, as far as I've understood the EliteBook g2 755 is a mess. Although I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and my laptop is slightly different (EliteBook g2 745) adding grub boot parameter *intremap=off* seems to have solved the problem.